# Bundled css link gets a 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am trying to get bundling to work in ASP.NET MVC 4.  I am getting a 404 error from the link generated for the bundled CSS.  I have done the following:

1. Installed the "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework" package via NuGet (v4.0.20710.0)
2. Created a BundleConfig class in the App_Start dir with the following contents:

   ```
   using System.Web.Optimization;
   namespace BsdAppTemplate.Web_Nancy.App_Start
   {
       public class BundleConfig
       {
           public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
           {
               bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/styles/cvi").Include(
                   "~/mainstyles.css"
               ));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Added the following to Web.config at site root:

   ```
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />

       <pages>
         <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
           ...
         </namespaces>
       </pages>
   </system.web>
   ```
4. Added the following to the head element of my MVC layout file:

   ```
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/cvi")
   ```
5. Copied the CSS file referenced in BundleConfig ("mainstyles.css") into the root directory of my web project.

When I view the source of a rendered file, I can see the link appears as:

```
<link href="/bundles/styles/cvi" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This link results in a 404 when browsing to it, or viewing the page request in Chrome's network tab.

I have also tried the equivalent on a web form, but I get the same result (404) from the link generated when I add:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/cvi") %>
```

Comment: From you description it seems that you have created `BundleConfig` class "by hand" are you sure that proper `RegisterBundles` method is being called in your `Application_Start` method?

Comment: @tpeczek - thanks, that is exactly what I was missing.  If you would re-enter this as an answer rather than a comment, I will mark it as the the answer.  Also, is there an alternative to setting this up by hand?  I was following this blog: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems that you have missed the step in which you apply your configuration by calling `RegisterBundles` in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    ...
}
```

Usually in cases where the `BundleConfig` class is already there (either as a part of the project template or created by NuGet package during the installation) this call is also already present - this is why many tutorials are implicit about it.

You should also be aware that the `BundleConfig` class is there for separation of concerns and in order to keep the `Application_Start` clean. In simple cases nothing prevents you from registering bundles directly in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/styles/cvi").Include("~/mainstyles.css"));

    ...
}
```

Comment: That makes sense - I had started from an empty MVC 4 project, so possibly that excludes the BundleConfig starter code.

Comment: i had the same issue to access font awesome fonts, for **other solutions**  try these links which deals with `StyleBundle` **virtualpath**: [Link 1](http://www.mvccentral.net/story/details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) , [Link 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774324.aspx?MVC4+css+bundling+and+image+references), [Link 3](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/10/25/font-awesome-4-0-mvc-bundling-and-minification/), [Link 4](http://jameschambers.com/2014/08/adding-some-font-awesome-to-mvc-and-bootstrap/) , hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 63):

Found this question via google results, but the problem in my case was Windows 2008 needed this in `web.config` to work when compilation debug=false.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

It worked fine on Win7 dev machine without this.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the solution that saved my day!

Comment: This entry was missing in my newly created vs 2015 web api project. Seems like a bug

Comment: What's strange is that on my dev machine, debug=false works fine, but once published to my staging server, this module was required.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem that my script bundle suddenly responded with 404. I a solution similar to @fiat answer that I found on [this blogpost](http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2012/11/fixing-404-errors-for-aspnet-mvc-apps.html).

The solution was to remove and add the `BundleModule` in the modules part section of the `system.webServer` section.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 5):

I hade same problem (in ASP.Net webform), i resolved my issue with Ignore "bundles/" route in Global.asax :

```
routeCollection.Ignore("bundles/{*catch}");
```

Comment: This had me scratching my head for days. Adding this solved my issue too. Thanks Mohsen.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this error while using Umbraco don't forget to add also this line to your web.config:

```
<add key="Umbraco.Core.ReservedUrls" value="~/bundles/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All my bundles names starting with "~/bundles/..." were not found in my WebAPI.
Adding the line to my RouteConfig.cs class

```
    routeCollection.Ignore("bundles/{*catch}");
```

fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'll share what happened to me, when working on my machine I was running with "debug=false" so each individual file was loaded but when pushing to stage/prod I got 404's from the `/bundles/styles`.

Turns out I has a rewrite rule that was forcing a trailing slash so a request to

`/bundles/styles` was redirected to `/bundle/styles/` which does not exist. Added a exception for the rewrite and now things works just fine.