# Windows 10 IIS does not load stylesheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

There are many post on web with regards to this problem, but none of them are working in my case. Recently I had to re-install IIS due to the problem caused by windows update. Javascript files and images are working fine, but stylesheets give me 404 error. When I open the stylesheet itself in browser I can see only blank page.

Here is what I have checked:

- The `.css` MIME Type is set
- IIS_IUSRS has correct permissions
- StaticFile Handler Mapping is enabled
- The stylesheet paths are definitely correct (existing project)
- Anonymous authentication is enabled and set to Application pool identity
- Removed staticContent section from `web.config`
- Static Content is installed under Programs and Features

Note that I am trying to sort this problem on localhost, not the server.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "on localhost, not the server"? All of the things you list there **has to be done on the server**.

Comment: What I mean is that I am trying to setup IIS on PC, not on the actual server where the sites are hosted from.

Comment: Have you sifted through the event logs and found any related errors there?

Comment: Nothing within the logs, which is weird. Unless I am looking at the wrong location `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\`

Comment: Where do you see 404 error? Browser networking?

Comment: @SeM yes, correct

Comment: did you tried Ctrl + F5?

Comment: Morpheus. open up the run window (`win + r`), type in `eventvwr`, hit enter and sift through THOSE logs for errors.

Comment: No logs in the event viewer either. @SeM yes, I did try :)

Comment: Also: new up a new .net project `dotnet new` or from visual studio. Deploy this application to IIS and see if it also fails to serve the css files. This could give you an indication if the problem is related to your project or IIS

Comment: @Marco, good hint, will try it now.

Comment: @Morpheus Do you mean, that you've copied that 404 error path and paste it on browser and it opened up a blank page?

Comment: @SeM exactly, yes

Comment: @Morpheus check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769662/bundled-css-link-gets-a-404-error)

Comment: @Marco thanks for your hint, now I know that the problem is with the website itself. It is using a versioning framework, which for some reason is no longer working. If you add your suggestion as an answer, I will be more then happy to accept it :)

Comment: Actually the problem is with URL rewrite module.

Comment: I did not really give an answer - this was just a hint to narrow down the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay as it is really unclear about why iis does not load style sheets. I would recommend you to install fiddler (a web debugging tool ) and do a debug to see if your css file actually gets requested or not or are you receiving a 404 error .